# If x in Column A then B-D copied to new sheet?

Tags: excel, copy-paste, formulas

I have a running list of names for everyone that we hire. Column A is titled "Errors", B is their start date, C is their first name and D is their last name. If I enter an X into column A I want their start date, first and last name to populate onto a different sheet so we can take notes on that error specifically. I've tried a bunch of different formulas but I can't seem to find anything that does what I need without enter loads of script which I would rather not do.

Comment: vba would be better.  Formulas will be an array type and depending on the amount of data might cause Excel to crash.

Comment: VBA it is - do you have anything that would be simple and effective?

Comment: In google sheets you could do this easily with the query formula or even the filter formula.